# Compile-time string hash

Tags: c++, c++11, hashcode

A while back [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93775/compile-time-sieve-of-eratosthenes) proposed a `constexpr` compile-time Sieve of Eratosthenes. It also linked to another SO question about compile-time computation of CRCs. I've found a place where I'd like to precompute the hash of a few C-strings, so I used those previous questions as a base.

I'm implementing the [one-at-a-time hash algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function) for C-style strings. I'm stuck to using C++11, so the function has to be recursive and without any local state:

```
namespace ct
{

constexpr std::uint32_t stringLength(const char * cstr)
{
    return (*cstr != '\0') ? (stringLength(cstr + 1) + 1) : 0;
}

constexpr std::uint32_t sumSHL(std::uint32_t h, std::uint32_t shift) { return h + (h << shift); }
constexpr std::uint32_t sumSHR(std::uint32_t h, std::uint32_t shift) { return h + (h >> shift); }
constexpr std::uint32_t xorSHR(std::uint32_t h, std::uint32_t shift) { return h ^ (h >> shift); }

constexpr std::uint32_t hashFinishImpl(std::uint32_t h)
{
    // h += (h <<  3)
    // h ^= (h >> 11)
    // h += (h << 15)
    return sumSHL(xorSHR(sumSHL(h, 3), 11), 15);
}

constexpr std::uint32_t hashStepImpl(std::uint32_t h, std::uint32_t c)
{
    // h += c
    // h += (h << 10)
    // h ^= (h >>  6)
    return xorSHR(sumSHL(h + c, 10), 6);
}

constexpr std::uint32_t hashImpl(const char * cstr, std::uint32_t length, std::uint32_t h)
{
    return (length != 0) ? hashImpl(cstr + 1, length - 1, hashStepImpl(h, *cstr)) : hashFinishImpl(h);
}

constexpr std::uint32_t hashCString(const char * cstr)
{
    return hashImpl(cstr, stringLength(cstr), 0);
}

} // namespace ct {}
```

I'm thinking it looks a bit convoluted, but couldn't think of a better way of handling it... Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks very clean to me and I already like it very much. A few minor remarks.

- Assuming that you'll probably want to provide this functionality in a header file, you should declare all your functions as `inline`. Even if they're not in a header file, it doesn't hurt to do so.
- Consider declaring your functions as `noexcept`, too.
- I'd prefer to see the implementation details hidden in a “`detail`” `namespace` to make it clear that only `hashCString` is supposed to be used directly. (Or is this assumption incorrect?)
- `ct::hashCString` is not the most descriptive name. I'd prefer if the name somehow indicated the implemented hash algorithm.
- You don't actually need the length of the string. Just replace `length != 0` with `*cstr != '\0'` in `hashImpl` and figure out the length as you go. This will save you one function.
- It seems to me that “`plus`” or “`add`” would be more consistent with “`xor`” than “`sum`” as the emphasis is on the operation.
- Your code assumes that `char` is an 8 bit integer. It would also be nice if you could hash arrays of `signed` and `unsigned` `char`s alike. Something like the following might do.

  ```
  template <typename CharT>
  constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<CharT>::value && (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(CharT) == 8), std::uint8_t>::type
  hashCString(const CharT *const s) noexcept;
  ```

  Instead of requiring `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(CharT) == 8`, you could relax it to `(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(CharT)) % 8 == 0` and manually loop over each octet in wider types. Smells like overkill, though.
- Another possible generalization would be to provide the classical interface that takes a pair of “begin” and “end” iterators. This might be handy for hashing sub-strings, strings with embedded zeros or strings that are not terminated with a 0 byte. You can still provide your single-argument version as a convenience overload.