# Sieve of Eratosthenes for small limits

Tags: c++, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I coded a sieve of Eratosthenes, I think it's quite fast for small limits. Any suggestions how to improve it? Especially for small limits, say limits < 50,000,000. (Also coded a parallel sieve (in C#) which finds the primes < 2^32 in 1.6 seconds, but it's relatively slow for small limits).

**How it works**

Let's find the primes <= 75. Odd composites are marked in an unsigned int array "x", each bit represents an odd number. The first (hexadecimal) number in x:

x[0] = 0x9B4B3491

- Binary: 1001 1011 0100 1011 0011 0100 1001 0001
- The lowest bit is set: 1 is not prime. The next bit isn't set: 3 is prime, etc.

x[1] = 0xFFFFFFE5

- Binary: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 0101
- Primes: 67, 71, 73

Count the primes, the 0-bits in x, with `__popcnt(unsigned int ...)`, (population count, number of set bits). `__popcnt(x[0])` gives the number of set bits, the number of odd composites. `__popcnt(~x[0])` gives the number of zero bits, the number of odd primes.

~x[0] = 0x64B4CB6E

- Binary: 0110 0100 1011 0100 1100 1011 0110 1110

~x[1] = 0x0000001A

- Binary: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 1010

~x[0] has 17 set bits, ~x[1] has 3, 20 odd primes. Resize the prime array "p" to 21. That's 20 odd primes and 1 even prime (2).

```
// Put the primes in "p", p[0] = 2
// Initialize: v = 1
// Count trailing zeros (tz), shift xi right by tz + 1:
//       xi = ~x[0] = ....101101101110  tz = 1, p[1] = v += tz << 1 =  3
//                                                 xi >>= tz + 1, v += 2
//                          1011011011  tz = 0, p[2] = v += tz << 1 =  5
//                                                 xi >>= tz + 1, v += 2
//                           101101101  tz = 0, p[3] = v += tz << 1 =  7
//                                                 xi >>= tz + 1, v += 2
//                            10110110  tz = 1, p[4] = v += tz << 1 = 11
//                                                 xi >>= tz + 1, v += 2
//                              101101  tz = 0, p[5] = v += tz << 1 = 13
//                                                 xi >>= tz + 1, v += 2
//                               10110  tz = 1, p[6] = v += tz << 1 = 17
//                                                 xi >>= tz + 1, v += 2
// 
// Results (Intel i7-4790 CPU @3.6 GHz from 2015):
// primes <= 100   109 ns
//        <= 200   187 ns
//        <= 400   312 ns
//        <= 800   578 ns
//        < 2^31   7.4 seconds
//        < 2^32  15.8 seconds

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned int u32;
vector<u32> x; vector<u32> p;

void buildX(u32 m)  // mark odd composites
{
    // make it safe:  1 << (int)(a >> 1)  =>    1 << (int)(a >> 1 & 31) ?
    //                1 << (int)d         =>    1 << (int)(d & 31)      ?
    //              ~0u << (int)m         =>  ~0u << (int)(m & 31)      ?

    m -= m / ~0u; m += m & 1; m >>= 1;
    x.resize((m >> 5) + 1); x[0] = 1;
    for (u32 a = 3, b = 4, c = 4, d; b < m; a += 2, b += c += 4)
        if ((x[a >> 6] & 1 << (int)(a >> 1)) == 0)
            for (d = b; d < m; d += a) x[d >> 5] |= 1 << (int)d;
    x[m >> 5] |= ~0u << (int)m;
}

void countPrimes()
{
    u32 c = 1; int i = x.size() - 1;
    while (i >= 0) c += __popcnt(~x[i--]);
    p.resize(c);
}

void primes(u32 m)  // primes <= m
{
    if (m > 1)
    {
        buildX(m); countPrimes(); p[0] = 2;
        u32 u = 1, v = 1, xi; DWORD tz;
        for (int i = 0, j = p.size(), n = 1;;)
        {
            xi = ~x[i++];
            while (xi)
            {
                _BitScanForward(&tz, xi); xi >>= tz; xi >>= 1;
                p[n++] = v += tz << 1; v += 2;
            }
            if (n >= j) break;
            v = u += 64;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    for (u32 m = 25; m <= 6400; m <<= 1)  // for (u32 m = 0; m < 9; m++)
    {
        primes(m);
        if (m > 1)
        {
            u32 maxP = p[p.size() - 1];
            cout << "largest prime <= " << m << " : " << maxP << "  ";
        }
        clock_t clock0 = clock();
        for (int i = 1000000; i; i--)
        {
            x.resize(0); p.resize(0); primes(m);
        }
        cout << clock() - clock0 << " ns: ";
        cout << p.size() << " primes" << endl << endl;
    }
    x.resize(0); p.resize(0); u32 m = ~0u;
    clock_t clock0 = clock(); primes(m);
    cout << (clock() - clock0) * 1e-3 << " s: ";      //  15.709 s
    cout << p.size() << " primes <= " << m << endl;

    x.resize(0); p.resize(0);
    clock0 = clock(); primes(m);
    cout << (clock() - clock0) * 1e-3 << " s: ";      //  15.522 s

    // 15.709 - 15.522 = 0.187 => memory allocation makes it ~ 1.2 % slower?

    cout << p.size() << " primes <= " << m << endl;
    for (int j = p.size(), i = j - 5; i < j;) cout << p[i++] << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: You're doing waaay too much on a single line, on many places in this code. Protip: any time you find yourself needing to write `;;`, that's a sign you're doing something wrong, stylistically.

Comment: I recommend reading Melissa O'Neill's https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf and seeing whether what you've got really has the appropriate big-O performance. I haven't checked but I *suspect* you've got quadratic performance in there right now.

Comment: The fastest runtime is obtained if the sieve is constructed at compile time.  See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93775/compile-time-sieve-of-eratosthenes

Comment: @Edward The fastest runtime is obtained by copying and pasting the first 75 primes from https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/10000.txt

Comment: You should not be changing or improving the code in your question in response to any answers you get.  This is specifically stated in the [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) in the help.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't know, of course it will never happen again. My intention was to treat the remarks in your excellent answer. Unfortunately, I know now, it is not allowed.

Comment: @Quuxplusone one needn't suspect, [just measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth). :) Personally, I found that article's wording extremely confusing. The math there clarified things, though.

Comment: @Quuxplusone `log(2, 15.8/7.4) = 1.094`.  *not* `2.0`. 15.8s up to 2^32 is respectable speed.

Comment: @P_P I used [`vector<bool>`](https://ideone.com/fapob) once, for nice and easy code, with comparable performance (to yours) *on ideone* (supposed to be slower than top boxes). And it's not even segmented. Runs at N^1.10 to your N^1.094, at the top range. (so, the same). See for yourself how simple it is. (`N` means upper limit; `~N^1.10` corresponds to `~n^1.16`, in *n* the number of primes). `vector<bool>` got the bad rap for not being proper vector. Who cares, if it's doing the job.

Comment: @Will Ness: Times (ms) for 3 sieves. Limits: 1e9, 2e9, 4e9. WN: 4254, 9531, 19905. PP: 3135, 6801, 14555. KW: 2047, 4352, 9094.  
KW (https://primesieve.org/segmented_sieve.html). One sieve returns primes ;)

Comment: @P_P Only *one* sieve returns primes? Which of the three? ;) Mine producing  a correct [count](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number+of+primes+below+2050000000&wal=header) and [value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=largest+prime+below+2050000000), I thought it must mean it's OK.

Comment: @P_P I don't understand your times. if 4254 means 4.254 seconds, then it is way slower than what Ideone reports (3.75s). You have 3.6GHz i7, it can't be that slow. (?)

Comment: @Will Ness: I should have said "one sieve makes an array of primes". It seems my i7 is that slow. I would be amazed if the relative times significantly changed on another system.

Comment: relative, of course not. I tried to run your code in ideone to compare the timings, but I don't know how to access POPCNT on gcc.

Comment: It's a little slower than popcnt, but because counting the bits is done in a few ms. or so, it's fast enough: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);
v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);
c = ((v + (v >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;

Answer (score 3):

Overall the code is a bit hard to read with the multiple statements per source line, multiple variable declarations (of different types) on one source line, and non-descriptive variable names.

You use a lot of hard coded constants, assuming that you're working with 32 bit integers.  Using named constants for these would make it clearer where some of your numbers come from, as well as allowing for an easier expansion to a 64 bit compilation.

The expression `1 << (int)d` used in `buildX` results in Undefined Behavior when `d` is larger than the number of bits used in the left operand (32 in this case).  Many hardware implementations of shift left reduce the shift count modulo the number of bits in the operand being shifted, so this is likely doing what you expect, but that is not guaranteed.

Since your vectors already have all the memory they need allocated when you enter your 1 million iteration timing loop, your times are solely for your algorithm and do not consider the time required for the memory allocations as the vectors expand.  The timing for your maximum case, since it only runs once, includes time spent growing the vectors.  (It's just 2 allocations, but is a difference in the timings.)

Answer (score 0):

A faster "buildX(u32 m)". Odd multiples of 3 are written
with three 32-bits words in "x", starting at x[1],
a simple solution for the first word: x[0] = 0x9b4b3491;
In a similar way the next prime(s) 5,7.. could be marked,
but with deminishing returns.

```
/*                   old-ns-new               old-s-new
     primes <   25     47    47    p < 2^31   7.4   7.1
            <   50     62    62      < 2^32  15.8  15.2
            <  100    109    94
            <  200    187   156
            <  400    312   250
            <  800    578   436
            < 1600   1092   843
            < 3200   2152  1700
            < 6400   4274  3385                          */

void buildX(u32 m)  // mark odd composites
{
    m -= m / ~0u; m += m & 1; m >>= 1;
    u32 a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = m >> 5;
    x.resize(d + 1); x[0] = 0x9b4b3491;
    for (; a <= d; a += 3) x[a] = 0x24924924;
    for (; b <= d; b += 3) x[b] = 0x49249249;
    for (; c <= d; c += 3) x[c] = 0x92492492;
    for (a = 5, b = 12, c = 8; b < m; a += 2, b += c += 4)
        if ((x[a >> 6] & 1 << (a >> 1)) == 0)
            for (d = b; d < m; d += a) x[d >> 5] |= 1 << d;
    x[m >> 5] |= ~0u << m;
}
```

Latest version: https://pastebin.com/JMdTxbeJ
Primes < 2^32 in 4.2 seconds.

Comment: wouldn't using the three words inside one loop body improve the locality of reference? `for (; a <= d; ) { x[a++] = 0x24924924; x[a++] = 0x49249249; x[a++] = 0x92492492; }`. in general, the point to the wheel optimization is not to mark them, but to ignore them altogether, so you don't need to mark them in the first place.

Comment: Overflow. This works, but it's slower: while(a<=d){x[a++]=0x24924924;if(a<=d){x[a++]=0x49249249;}if(a<=d){x[a++]=0x92492492;}}

Comment: adjust `d` instead, before the loop.

Comment: I tried different solutions do you mind to show your "adjust d.." code, so I can try it? Two years ago I coded an isPrime function (no wheels ;) My fastest sieve (not for small limits) is based on it: http://bigintegers.blogspot.com/2016/08/odd-prime-sieve.html

Comment: I mean just round it down to the biggest multiple of 3 not above your current `d`. then manually finish the marking with zero, one or two `x[a++]= ...` assignments, according to the remainder you got when rounding it down. (I can hear your "d'oh!", almost). :)

Comment: I didn't find `isPrime()` on that page. and why do you say it's "*almost* a sieve of Eratosthenes", there? It's too complex for me to see right away what it's doing exactly (same here btw), but I didn't see any trial divisions / %s there, for sure. :) --- The timing makes sense. My code runs abut 8.5 seconds for that range on ideone, /4 cores, (or should it be /8 ?) /2 for segmentation --> ~ 1 second, give or take.

Comment: "Almost SoE" because for example 97x97 hasn't been marked by thread A, thread B might mark multiples of 97x97 (in a small range). Tried "adjust d..: Same timings, but code gets less clear. Got a warning: Avoid discussions, moved the discussion to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74354/discussion-between-p-p-and-will-ness).