# Project Euler #5 in C++

Tags: c++, beginner, programming-challenge

I'm currently doing the Project Euler challenges to learn C++. The fifth problem is the following.

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>
> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

I thought of a loop between 20 and 10 as everything under 10 is a multiple of something under 10. At each iteration, the result is the lcm of the loop variable and the current result.

If I am correct, the complexity of this should be \$\mathcal{O}(n/2)\$. Am I right?

Is there any faster/better/cleaner implementation or another algorithm with a better complexity?

This is my code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

long gcd(long a, long b)
{
    long t;

    if (b == 0) return a;

    while (b != 0) {
        t = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = t;
    }
    return a;
}

long lcm(long a, long b)
{
    return (a * b) / gcd(a, b);
}

int main()
{
    long n(20), result(1);
    for (long i = n; i > n/2; --i) {
        result = lcm(result, i);
    }
    std::cout << "Result: " << result << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review!  This is actually pretty good code for a beginner, but here are some things that may help you improve your program.

### Simplify the code

The `gcd` routine looks like this:

```
long gcd(long a, long b)
{
    long t;

    if (b == 0) return a;

    while (b != 0) {
        t = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = t;
    }
    return a;
}
```

It can be simplified in three ways.  First, we can declare `t` within the loop.  Second, we can eliminate the `if` statement entirely.  Third, we can simplify the while loop condition to simply `while (b)` which is the same as `while (b != 0)`:

```
long gcd(long a, long b)
{
    while (b) {
        long t = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = t;
    }
    return a;
}
```

### Use `const` where appropriate

The value of `n` is constant, so it would make sense to declare it either `const` or even better `constexpr`.

### Consider signed versus unsigned

It's always worth thinking about the *domain* of the numbers in a calculation.  In this case, it seems that all of the numbers are probably intended to be unsigned, but they're declared `long` which gives signed numbers.

### Think of alternative algorithms and implementations

I think your algorithm is fast enough, but an alternative approach would instead be to calculate all of the *unique* prime factors of all of the numbers < 20 and simply multiply them together.  With the judicious use of `constexpr`, one could even calculate everything at compile-time which would make for a very fast calculation.  For inspiration, see [Compile-time sieve of Eratosthenes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93775/compile-time-sieve-of-eratosthenes)

Comment: If we declare `t` within the loop it will be redeclared for each pass in the loop, does this change something in term of pure performance?

Comment: Generally, declaring variables with the minimal possible scope allows the compiler to make better decisions regarding register allocation.  However with code as small and simple as yours, it probably doesn't make a huge difference with modern compilers.

Comment: OK, I thought there was some specific assembly instruction executed when declaring a variable. I know this doesn't matter right here but I'm interested in optimization.

Comment: The condition `while (b)` is a bad abbreviation. For anything other than a boolean or a stream I prefer the explicit form `while (b != 0)`. Having this implicit type conversion is not helpful for human readers.

Comment: @RolandIllig: I prefer it with the shorter syntax.  Regardless of which one uses, it's helpful to understand that they are 100% equivalent.